# How to get coordinates of cropped image in the original image

Tags: flutter

Is there a way in the flutter plugin image_cropper to get the coordinates of the cropped image in the original image?
Currently only the croppedFile as file will be returned, is it possible to get the coordinate information too?

```
 File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
                sourcePath: _image.path,
                androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
                    toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
                    toolbarColor: Colors.blue,
                    toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
                    initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                    lockAspectRatio: false,
                    hideBottomControls: true),
                iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
                  minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
                ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Write like this will print the coordinates of the cropped file

```
File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    sourcePath: imageFile,
    aspectRatioPresets: [
      CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
    ],
    androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
      toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      lockAspectRatio: false,
    ),
    iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
      minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
    ));
setState(() {
  userSelectedImage = croppedFile;
  print("croppedFile ${croppedFile}");
});
```

Comment: this only prints the file location but not the coordiantes from the original picture